# how to import mjs in vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, es6-modules

Is it possible to make a vscode extension made of mjs files?

because I tried to make an extension with mjs files only, in order to have full es6 features without TypeScript.
But it does not run:

If I make the extension with `$ vsce package` it does not give any error but it makes an extension that does not work when installed: the contributions that I've put in the package.json are present but vscode shows an error popup that says

> Activating extension 'my.ext' failed: Must use import to load ES Module: c:\vsext\extension.mjs.

and every command I try to run gives an error

> command 'my.cmd' not found

If I run the extension on the debugger, and the breakpoint on uncaught exception option flagged, it breaks on /src/vs/workbench/api/node/extHostExtensionService.ts:88.

After further search, I noticed that this exception is generatend when the script tries to load the first mjs module.

there is something I can do in order to include my mjs library files?

I think that this behaviour could also impact the use of npm modules with mjs files.

---

### EDIT

Found (kind of) a  way using esm:

*The idea is to use esm to handle es6 imports and share the vscode object between  imported modules*

this could seem quite tricky but when I tried to just `import * as vscode from "vscode"` im my mjs files, vscode complained that **can't find module vscode**.

**so I've done the following**

- add 'esm' as dependency
- in all the files where vscode is used, remove the import of vscode and add something like this function

```js
var vscode; // will store vscode obj
export function IMPORTVSCODE(vscodeInstance){
    vscode = vscodeInstance
}
```

- create a init file where you require vscode (with node native require) and your main module (with esm require)
- in the init file call main.IMPORTVSCODE(vscode)
- on all the files A that imports a file B that need vscode, before use the exported stuff from file B, call B.IMPORTVSCODE(vscode)

---

**for example**

```js
// init.js
const vscode = require("vscode")
const esm = require("esm")(module/*, options*/)
const main = esm("./main.mjs")
main.IMPORTVSCODE(vscode)
module.exports = main

// main.mjs
import * as other from "./other.mjs"
var vscode; // will store vscode obj
export function IMPORTVSCODE(vscodeInstance){
    vscode = vscodeInstance
}
function activate(){
  other.IMPORTVSCODE(vscode)
  other.methodThatNeedsVscode()
}

// other.mjs
var vscode; // will store vscode obj
export function IMPORTVSCODE(vscodeInstance){
    vscode = vscodeInstance
}
export function methodThatNeedsVscode(){
    vscode // ...use vscode
}
```

---

**My extension runs fine now!**

But I think that better ideas could be found, so if somebody has some finest solutions, please share them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use pure ESM (thank god), even though you have to start through with CJS. The trick is to use `await import`:

```js
/**
 * @param {import('vscode').ExtensionContext} context - The context.
 */
async function activate(context) {
  (await import('./register-hello-world.mjs')).activate(context);
  (await import('./register-hello-tensor.mjs')).activate(context);
}
module.exports.activate = activate;
```

**register-hello-world.mjs**:

```js
import {add} from '#customImport';
import {vscode} from '#vscode';
/**
 * This method is called when your extension is activated, which
 * happens the very first time the command is executed.
 * @param {import('vscode').ExtensionContext} context - The context.
 */
export function activate(context) {
  // Use the console to output diagnostic information (console.log) and errors (console.error)
  // This line of code will only be executed once when your extension is activated
  console.log('> register extension.helloWorld');
  // The command has been defined in the package.json file
  // Now provide the implementation of the command with registerCommand
  // The commandId parameter must match the command field in package.json
  const disposable = vscode.commands.registerCommand('extension.helloWorld', () => {
    vscode.window.showInformationMessage(`Hello World! add(10, 20) is ${add(10, 20)}`);
  });
  context.subscriptions.push(disposable);
}
```

Now you may wonder - what is that `import {vscode} from '#vscode';`?

You can basically use your `package.json` like an importmap:

```json
{
  "name": "vscode-extension-transformers",
  "displayName": "vscode-extension-transformers",
  "description": "Transformers.js example for VS Code",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "publisher": "kungfooman",
  "repository": "https://github.com/kungfooman/vscode-extension-transformers/",
  "scripts": {
    "watch": "echo Begone, watch build step! Embracing true ESM power!",
    "vscode:prepublish": "echo Begone, prepublish build step! Embracing true ESM power!",
    "lint": "eslint \"src/**/*.js\""
  },
  "engines": {
    "vscode": "^1.74.0"
  },
  "categories": [
    "Other"
  ],
  "activationEvents": [],
  "main": "./src/extension.js",
  "contributes": {
    "commands": [
      {
        "command": "extension.helloWorld",
        "title": "Hello World"
      },
      {
        "command": "extension.helloTensor",
        "title": "Hello Tensor"
      }
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^16.18.34",
    "@types/vscode": "^1.73.0",
    "eslint": "^8.26.0"
  },
  "imports": {
    "#customImport": "./src/customImport.mjs",
    "#vscode": "./src/vscode.mjs"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@xenova/transformers": "^2.6.1"
  }
}
```

And **./src/vscode.mjs** has to look like this:

```js
import {createRequire} from 'node:module';
const require = createRequire(import.meta.url);
export const vscode = require('vscode');
```

Tada, problems solved - have fun with ESM. If you use TypeScript, drop it now: it just creates extra headaches through AST transformations etc.

Too much code? I made a complete test repo here:

https://github.com/kungfooman/vscode-extension-transformers